# How to download GitHub issue attachment from command line?

Tags: github, download, attachment, github-issues, github-organizations

I'm trying to download files that were attached to issues for a repository within my organization from command line. Specifically, I'm trying to download using R, but command line will do. I have the URL, which takes the form https://github.com/<org>/<repo>/files/<number>/<file>.

Whenever I try using curl or wget for example, nothing happens because the file is blocked by an authentication wall. I've also tried `curl \<url> -u "\<username>:\<token>"`, but to no avail.